# cannot see the changed value of a jquery cloned input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html code

```
     <div class="span4 child_age_box">
           <input class="child_age_input" value="2">
     </div>
```

And following jquery which I want to clone and append the block when an event is triggered.

```
var child_value_input= $('.child_age_input');

var add_box = function (){$('.child_ages').on("change",function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.child_age_box').empty();
   for(var i= 0; i< parseInt($(this).val()); i++){
            $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.child_age_box').append(child_value_input.clone().show().get(0).outerHTML)
}});
```

It seems ok , when I trigger the event. The box appears and I can put some value in it. But when I ask for the `$('.child_age_input')`. I can not see the value that I put in the text box. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't trust the `outerHTML`, get the actual value with `.val()` instead. If the value attribute is 2 in the source code, the outerHTML will still show 2 even if you change it (at least in Chrome):

```
var fld = $('.child_age_input');
fld.val('3');
$(document.body).append(fld.clone());

$('.child_age_input').each(function(){
   console.log(this.outerHTML, $(this).val()); 
   // 2x <input class="child_age_input" value="2"> 3 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HQsrQ/

Comment: When I do,`$(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.child_age_box').append(child_value_input.clone())` new boxes does not come when

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking this is causing the error
`$(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.child_age_box').empty()`
you are calling `empty()` so the `child_age_input` element is removed from the DOM

on another note instead of `parent().parent()` so on you can use `closest()`